# Copy text from TextView

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
Button copy;
Button previous;
Button more;
TextView screen;
String quote=screen.getText().toString();
```

I need the button copy to copy the value of the variable `quote`. How can I do this? I've tried:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
clipboard.setText(screen.getText());
```

but it works only on Android 4.0+ devices.

Comment: Why all people vote down before commenting :(((

Comment: @Jouni "how to accept?" Go back to previous questions you have asked and click the Check mark next to answers given if they answered your question.

Comment: Are you using compatibility library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your import is wrong.

Use

```
import android.text.ClipboardManager ;
```

and not

```
import android.content.ClipboardManager; // this was instroduced only in API level 11
```

Comment: eclipe is saying "The type ClipboardManager is deprecated"

Comment: Yeah, it is deprecated for content.clipboardmanager that you were trying to use. If you want to use clipboardmanager in Gingerbread and below device then you will have to use deprecated class

Comment: do i have to import both
import android.content.ClipboardManager; 
& import android.text.ClipboardManager ;

Comment: that is fine. if you change the sdk version, it will not be striked out. But since you want compatibility with older versions, you will need to use this. You dont have any other option. You cannot import both

Comment: no you can keep using the latest sdk but use the striked out clipboardmanager. Its just telling you that there is a better version of clipboardmanager. but since you cannot use on < 4.0 devices, you can continue to use the old one